# print values of each key in the dictionary with python

Tags: python, dictionary

How to print the values of each key in the dictionary with python?
For example this dictionary:

```
{
 'switch1':'s1-eth1,s1-eth2',
 'switch2':'s2-eth1,s2-eth2'
}
```

My expected output:

```
'switch1':'s1-eth1'
'switch1':'s1-eth2'
'switch2':'s1-eth1'
'switch2':'s1-eth2'
```

I tried these methods but my answer is not because I need a loop to give me any value of that key separately to help the command I want to run:

```
year_of_creation = {'Python': 1993, 'JavaScript': 1995, 'HTML': 1993}
1-print(year_of_creation.items())
2-print(year_of_creation.values())
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

To print the values of each key in a dictionary separately, you can use a loop to iterate over the dictionary items and then print each key-value pair individually.

example:

```py
dictionary = {
    'switch1': 's1-eth1,s1-eth2',
    'switch2': 's2-eth1,s2-eth2'
}

for key, values in dictionary.items():
    value_list = values.split(',')
    for value in value_list:
        print(f"{key}: {value}")
# switch1: s1-eth1
# switch1: s1-eth2
# switch2: s2-eth1
# switch2: s2-eth2
```

Answer (score 0):

I know someone else already answered it, but I decided to have a little fun with it.

Here's a neat little one-liner that works but you shouldn't use to avoid getting bullied by your mates:

```py
print('\n'.join([f"{key}: {value}" for key, values in dictionary.items() for value in values.split(',')]))
```